# Android application exiting abruptly during database query

Tags: android

When I tried to do database query from my activity class, the application ended abruptly. I checked logcat, it showed 'Skipped this many frames. The application may be doing to much work on it's main thread'. Then I tried using Thread, but still it abruptly ends.
Code snippet

```
if(v == findViewById(R.id.btnlogin)) {
        if((tlogid.length()>0) && (tpwd.length()>0)) {

            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
            final DBQuery dbq = new DBQuery();
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dbq.queryforAccount(tlogid, tpwd, getApplicationContext());
                }
            };
            try {
                t.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final Cursor c = dbq.getCursor();

            if(c.getCount() > 0) {
                Bundle detail = new Bundle();
                detail.putString("Accountid", c.getString(0));
                detail.putString("Loginid", c.getString(1));
                detail.putString("Name", c.getString(2));
                i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Welcome_user.class);
                i.putExtras(detail);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

But still the app ends, showing Null pointer exception in the Logcat.